# How can i make requests in a loop in ReadyAPI with different data and response should be generated in another file?

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api, groovyscriptengine

I have a request body in ReadyAPI project. I have different data for a particular field in Request Body. Is there a way how I can loop the request with different data each time?

the goal is to have a file where 100's of different data responses are saved.

[I have explained my requirement in a diagram please refer to it for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TAIs.png)

Comment: Have you seen the [documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/data-driven/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is a data-driven test.  If you have a licensed version of SoapUI, then this is standard functionality.

If you don't then there are custom solutions built by users.  Search for "soapui data driven test' on here.